# cordova crashes after adding cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I did the following:

```
ionic start testproject tabs
cd testproject
ionic setup sass
ionic platform add android
ionic build
ionic run android
```

And it works, runs great on the emulator.

And then I did:

```
ionic start testproject2 tabs
cd testproject2
ionic setup sass
ionic platform add android
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
ionic build
ionic run android
```

And then it crashes.

My specs:

```
Emulator: Genymotion, Custom Phone 5.0.0 - API 21
Cordova: Checked on 6.1 and 5.4.1
ionic: 1.7.14
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview: 1.6.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The root config.xml template includes the following reference:

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="17+" />
```

Delete it, and do a:

```
cordova build android
```

That should get it running